# When can the variance be written as a function of expectation?

Tags: distributions, variance, generalized-estimating-equations

1. What kinds of distribution  have variance as a function of expectation, i.e. let $X$ be a random variable of a distribution, $Var(X) = f(E(X))$ for some function $f$ ? Sufficient conditions including typical examples of distribution (such as [exponential family distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family), or even [natural exponential family distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_exponential_family)), and/or necessary conditions will be fine. I saw
   this is assumed in [Generalized Estimating Equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_estimating_equation).

   In particular, in the natural dispersed exponential family with pdf
   $f (y; θ, φ) = \exp\left(\frac{yθ − b(θ)}{a(φ)}+ c(y, φ)\right)$, 
   is there always a function $V( · )$ such that $Var(X) = V(E(X))a(φ)$? See [this note](http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~xianghua/8452/note/05GEE.pdf).
2. Does "[variance structure or variance function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_estimating_equation)" refer to that the variance can be written
   as a function of the mean?
3. If $E(X) = f(\theta)$, and $Var(X) = f'(\theta)$, is $Var(X)$ a
   function of $E(X)$? One example that satisfies the condition is a canonical exponential family distribution.

Comment: This question seems to arise from some confusion, at least of terminology. A "distribution" has a *definite* expectation and a *definite* variance. In a *family of distributions*, the expectation and variance can be considered functions of the distribution. One might then ask for what families it is the case that for any given expectation, there is at most one variance corresponding to it (this is the definition of "function"). But that's obviously too broad to be answerable (and is purely mathematical anyway). You seem to be reacting to something: please give an explicit reference.

Comment: @whuber: I updated my post.

Comment: @Tim be aware when we have variance of a distribution *f(x)*, then such variance is not a function of *x*. similarly *E(x)*. I think you mixed up things, if a distribution have ranges *0 to y* then there is possibility which you mention. Such expectation may be the function of parameters not possible for original variables.